# what happens when awk does finds nothing

Tags: linux, bash, awk

i tried to use awk to find some fields in a file using a bash script, if the field exists it executes the required commands, but if it does not exists it does not execute the required commands. Am not quite sure what am doing wrong.

this is the script problems.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#what happens awk finds nothing

check(){
    (awk '$0 =="milk" {print $1}' trial.txt \
    | uniq -c \
    | awk '{ if ($1 > 1) \
    print $1 ,"record found"; \
    else if($1 == 1)
    print $1, "record of " $2 ,"found";
    else if($1 == "")\
    print "no record of " $2 ,"found";\
    else if(length($1) == 0)
    print "no record of " $2 , "found";\
    else
    print "nothing happened here"

    }')
}


echo "what happens when awk finds nothing"
check
```

this is the trial.txt file

```
choco
milk
ginger
bread
milk
apple
```

**output**>>what happens when awk finds nothing
2 record found

i tried this and there was no output

```
#!/bin/bash
#what happens awk finds nothing

check(){
    (awk '$0 =="fire" {print $1}' trial.txt \
    | uniq -c \
    | awk '{ if ($1 > 1) \
    print $1 ,"record found"; \
    else if($1 == 1)
    print $1, "record of " $2 ,"found";
    else if($1 == "")\
    print "no record of " $2 ,"found";\
    else if(length($1) == 0)
    print "no record of " $2 , "found";\
    else
    print "nothing happened here"

    }')
}


echo "what happens when awk finds nothing"
check
```

**output**>>

Comment: Does `trial.txt` use DOS line endings? If so, `$0` ends with a carriage return, unlike the value you compare it to.

Comment: What are _“the required commands”_? Also, when you filter out everything but `milk` or everything but `fire`, what is the `uniq -c` good for?

Comment: Instead of `check() { ( ... ) }`, you can write `check() ( ... )` and get the same result.  (Although it doesn't appear that you need a subshell at all here, so you can just drop the inner parentheses.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when searching for `fire`:

- 1st `awk` script finds nothing so generates ***NO*** output
- follow-on `uniq` has no input so it also generates ***NO*** output
- 2nd `awk` script is thus fed the equivalent of an ***empty*** file
- 2nd `awk` script only prints a message when it has an input line to process

One approach to handling an empty file (ie, no input lines) is to add some logic in an `END {}` block; adding an `END{}` block to OP's 2nd `awk`:

```
awk '
    {      if ($1 > 1)          print $1 ,"record found"
      else if ($1 == 1)         print $1, "record of " $2 ,"found"
      else if ($1 == "")        print "no record of " $2 ,"found"
      else if (length($1) == 0) print "no record of " $2 , "found"
    }
END {      if (NR==0)           print "nothing happened here" }
'
```

---

Generally speaking once you decide to use `awk` there's usually no need for the `uniq`, nor the need for multiple `awk` calls.

Consider one possible rewrite of the `check()` function:

```
check() {
awk -v x="${1}" '
$0 == x { c++ }
END     {      if (c > 1)   print c, "records of", x, "found"
          else if (c == 1)  print c, "record of",  x, "found"
          else              print "no record of",  x, "found"
        }
' trial.txt
}
```

Take for a test drive:

```
$ check milk
2 records of milk found

$ check choco
1 record of choco found

$ check fire
no record of fire found
```

Comment: the second solution worked fine for me